# Laravel policy always return false

Tags: laravel, policy

I made a policy for one model.the policy class as following:

```
namespace App\Policies;
use App\User;
use App\Models\Address;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class AddressPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    public function delete(User $user, Address $address)
    {
        return $user->id === $address->user_id ;
    }
}
```

And I register the policy in authServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Address ;
use App\Policies\AddressPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Address::class => AddressPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
```

I use this policy in a controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Models\Address;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth ;

class AddressController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function destroy(Address $address)
    {

        $this->authorize('delete', $address);
        $address->delete();
        return response()->json(['msg'=>'success'], 200);  
    }
```

when I request the destroy method in the controller, it always return a 403 status, when I remove this line "$this->authorize ('delete', $address)",the data can be deleted.I've tried several solutions and searched many same problem, none of them resolved my problem.

Comment: try to use the string name of the class `'App\Models\Address' => 'App\Policies\AddressPolicy',` instead of `Address::class => AddressPolicy::class,` !

Comment: I have tried that ,but still the same result

Comment: try to do `return false;` instead of `return $user->id === $address->user_id ;` just for test !

Comment: no matter return true or false,the response status is always 403(unauthorized)

Comment: sorry.I made a mistake in the model namespace

Comment: It's ok, good that you find out the problem your self ;)